# Do you reuse values from a select box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say that I have a select box in an `html` page. And the values in that select box come from a db query that returns a not so small list of options.
Now if I need to add another 4 select boxes showing the same list of options, would I have to duplicate the code and so send back to the browser `4*(select_box_result_size)` or this is normally done differently?

Comment: What server code are you using?

Comment: @Ted:Does my question depend on server side technology? I am asking about the generated html

Comment: It does and it doesn't. If e.g. you were using a loop on the server to generate the options, why not generate them 4 times for 4 different controls but in 1 iteration? And that's without even getting into the why you need the same data 4 times :):)

Comment: On the client you can use jQuery to get all the html of the select control and copy it into another control. You would still have duplicated data though, but at least it won't have to go through the wire again.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how you are managing the server-side code, the answer is that each select box needs its own group of options. That said, if all options are the same then you should only make one query to your database, and generate the all the select boxes you need with a single function. Simply get the options from the database, store them in a variable and then create your boxes.

Do note that in your HTML each box will have the values hardcoded into it, so your client-side code will have duplicate data, but that doesn't really matter. What is important is that the code that you'll have to maintain is clean, and that you put as little stress as possible on your database. One query + one function is all you need.

---

If performance was *really* an issue, you always have the possibility of dynamically-generating the combo boxes using JavaScript. You could essentially embed one and then copy it four more times. However there are two things you need to consider for this:

1. Do you *really* have a performance issue that is being caused by these combo boxes? (Probably not)
2. Is the combo box so big that it will actually take longer to load the HTML across a network connection than it will to copy the box four times with JavaScript? (Again, probably not... remember that the longer the box the longer it will take to copy.)

Unless you have 1000+ options, I would recommend to simply stick to generating the box four times. If you do have that many then do two things:

1. Benchmark. Create two pages, one with a single combo box and one with four and compare the size. Then compare the load times.
2. Consider improving your UI. Perhaps if you have 1000 options it would be better for the end user to implement some sort of filtering process to reduce the number of necessary elements... i.e. If you have a box containing all the cities of the world, have one box to select the country and then populate the city box with only the applicable cities by way of a JSON request.

Comment: `note that in your HTML each box will have the values hardcoded into it, so your client-side code will have duplicate data`.That is exactly the gist of my question.I understand that in dynamic html the html on server is created by any technology we use but I was wondering if the fact that the generated html *send* to the client would necessarily have these hardcoded values duplicated 4 times (so extra network load) or there is another way this is done

Answer (score 0):

> And the values in that select box come from a db query that returns a
>   not so small list of options.

For user friendliness you could try autosuggest, there are libraries for that but you could try writing your own.

If same data is displayed multiple times (4 times) depending on your server side script it might be best to fetch the data in memory and generate the selects instead of querying 4 times.

> would I have to duplicate the code

It's best not to duplicate, at the very least you can write a helper function to generate the select list. If you're serious about removing code from html markup you can look into using one of the many MVC frameworks out there that use templates and allow you to bind data to it.